# Can Noether's theorem be applied to cyclic time symmetries?

Tags: conservation-laws, symmetry, time, noethers-theorem, discrete

[Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) relates continuous symmetries in the time evolution of a system to a conserved value.  Many conserved values, such as conservation of momentum, can be described via this theorem.  I'm interested in whether there is a meaningful conserved value for a cyclic time symmetry, $t^\prime = t + \tau$, where $\tau$ is not an infintessimal perturbation.

From what I can tell, that symmetry is not a continuous symmetry, so I should not be able to apply Nother's thorem.  However, intuitively things like standing waves *feel* like there's a conservation law that governs them (less general than conservation of energy or momentum).  Of course, feelings are not the same as mathematical truths.  Is there a clever mathematical way to treat a cyclic time symmetry which permits the application of Nother's theorem or a related corollary, or is this simply a perfect example of what Nother's theorem can't speak to?

Comment: Isotropy of space is invariance under rotations, with a cyclic variable - angle. One nevertheless gets conservation of angular momentum. I would guess therefore that there would be a conserved quantity for cyclic dependence on time, but I do not have time to check it now

Comment: Whilst I'm not sure I can answer your question, it would be well worth looking at Frank Wilczek's recent work on classical (and quantum) time crystals - https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.109.160402.

Comment: @Cryo you only get conservation of angular momentum if your space is invariant under continuous rotations.There's no conserved quantity corresponding to a rotation by 360 degrees.

Comment: @John Dvorak. Yep. I missed that OP was not talking about continuous & cyclic, but only the latter. Thanks for correcting me